# UIColor extension convenience init not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
convenience init(red:Int,green:Int,blue:Int,alpha:CGFloat) {
    var red:   CGFloat = CGFloat(red)/255.0
    var green: CGFloat = CGFloat(green)/255.0
    var blue:  CGFloat = CGFloat(blue)/255.0
    self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)
}
```

I wrote the code above to give a more convenience way of declaring my custom uicolor. But somehow, it crashes my app by calling itself until stack overflows. What is wrong here?

Also, I just realised that I am not explicitly calling this init function. But rather I was calling `UIColor.whiteColor()` when this error occurs. Of course, if I explicitly call this function, error occurs still!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't see any inconvenience doing it just like this:

```
let myCustomColorHSBa = UIColor(hue: 120/360, saturation: 0.25 , brightness: 1.0 , alpha: 1)
let myCustomColorRGBa = UIColor(red: 191/255, green: 1, blue: 191/255, alpha: 1)
```

but if you really need one, you can do as follow:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(red: Int = 0, green: Int = 0, blue: Int = 0, opacity: Int = 255) {
        precondition(0...255 ~= red   &&
                     0...255 ~= green &&
                     0...255 ~= blue  &&
                     0...255 ~= opacity, "input range is out of range 0...255")
        self.init(red: CGFloat(red)/255, green: CGFloat(green)/255, blue: CGFloat(blue)/255, alpha: CGFloat(opacity)/255)
    }
}
```

---

```
UIColor(red: 255)               // r 1.0 g 0.0 b 0.0 a 1.0  (Red)
UIColor(red: 255, green: 255)   // r 1.0 g 1.0 b 0.0 a 1.0  (Yellow)
UIColor(red: 255, blue: 255)    // r 1.0 g 0.0 b 1.0 a 1.0  (Magenta)

UIColor(green: 255)             // r 0.0 g 1.0 b 0.0 a 1.0  (Green)
UIColor(green: 255, blue: 255)  // r 0.0 g 1.0 b 1.0 a 1.0  (Cyan)

UIColor(blue: 255)              // r 0.0 g 0.0 b 1.0 a 1.0  (Blue)
UIColor(red: 255, green: 192, blue: 203)  // r 1.0 g 0.753 b 0.796 a 1.0 (Pink)
UIColor(red: 255, green: 215)   // r 1.0 g 0.843 b 0.0 a 1.0 (Gold)
```

Comment: The trick here is the convenience init must have differently named parameters to the UIColor init.

Comment: After a bit trying myself, I think Robert Wagstaff gave the right explanation. I dont think Swift allows overloading of different types of same parameters. Wonder if its done deliberately or it will be allowed in the future

Comment: I was just expecting good answers on a lot of my questions if that bothers you at all.

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be to do it like this (swift 3)

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a:CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: a/255)
    }  
}

let myColor = UIColor(r:255, g:255, b:255, a:255)
```