# Changing View Background Color in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I am trying to change the background color of a view programatically. This code works fine (within my viewDidLoad):

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

However this doesn't:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 44, green: 62, blue: 80, alpha: 1.0)
```

What is the reason for this, and what would be the best workaround?

Comment: `UIColor` takes values from 0 to 1. You want `UIColor(red: 44.0/255.0, green: 62.0/255.0, blue: 80.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)`

Comment: You can use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27736004/2303865

Comment: @originaluser2 no need to add .0 to them. The compiler deducts their type 44/255 would work as well

Comment: ah true, too used to the ways of obj-c ;)