# Why we should go for convenience Initializers than manual initializers

Tags: ios, swift

As per my understanding the convenience initializers are to `init` missing properties with default or hard coded values or giving implementation with any flexible number of parameters and satisfying **init rule** i.e all properties should be initialized before object creation.

Like:

```
class A {

    var name:String;
    var salary:Float;

    init(name:String,salary:Float) {
        self.name = name;
        self.salary = salary;
    }

    convenience init(name:String) {
        self.init(name:name , salary:8000.0)
    }

}
```

But we can also achieve this with the following code and getting output:

```
class A {

    var name:String;
    var salary:Float;

    init(name:String,salary:Float) {
        self.name = name;
        self.salary = salary;
    }

     init(name:String) {
        self.name = name;
        self.salary = 8000.0;
    }

    init() {
        self.name = "UnKnown name";
        self.salary = 0.0;
    }
}

let objectA = A(name: "murali")
print(objectA.name);
print(objectA.salary);
```

**Output:**

```
murali
8000.0
```

Give me clarification on which cases we will use convenience Initializers.

Comment: You use them wherever you find them *convenient*.. hence the name.  They are just to make your life easier if you choose to use them.

Comment: Means i can place convenience keyword in front of 2nd and 3rd methods and delegating a call to main init method in second version of class A .it will just increase the readability right ?

Comment: sed 's/;//g' please ;-)

Comment: If you want to know when to use it you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27736004/2303865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple cases like your example there isn't a big difference in using `convenience init` or manually setting the property.

Convenience initialisers come in handy when after setting your properties you have to perform some complicated logic and don't want to duplicate your code.

This

```
class A {

    var name:String;
    var salary:Float;

    init(name:String,salary:Float) {
        self.name = name;
        self.salary = salary;

        //hundreds of line of very complicated logic in order to perform important stuff
    }

    convenience init(name:String) {
        self.init(name:name , salary:8000.0)
    }

}
```

is more readable, and easier to understand and manage for future changes, than this

```
class B {

    var name:String;
    var salary:Float;

    init(name:String,salary:Float) {
        self.name = name;
        self.salary = salary;

        //hundreds of lines of very complicated logic in order to perform important stuff
    }

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name;
        self.salary = 8000.0;

        //the same, repeated, hundreds of lines as before of very complicated logic in order to perform the same important stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: @Boshi : Sorry for my innocent question i.e we can make a separate method and call that from different int methods. We should not ?

Comment: I think same redundant code of all init methods its self is happening in my code  . I.e assignment of properties

Comment: That'd work as well. I think the convenience initialiser is more readable, but that's up to you to choose the one you prefer the most.