# How to transition scenes in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game, and where I want to transition scenes. However, I am getting this error when using transitioning scenes:

> [Graphics] UIColor created with component values far outside the expected range. Set a breakpoint on UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents to debug. This message will only be logged once. 3fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value 2017-01-09 16:58:33.716407 MyGameApp[18371:5784169] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Does anyone know what is going on?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class Congrats: SKScene {
 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


   backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(248), green: CGFloat(248), blue: CGFloat(248), alpha: CGFloat(255)) //SKColor

    var message = "Good Job! "
    let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold")
    label.text = message
    label.fontSize = 22
    label.fontColor = SKColor.blue
    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.black
    label.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    addChild(label)        
     run(SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0),
        SKAction.run() {
            let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 1.0)
            let scene = GameOver(size: (self.view?.frame.size)!)                
            self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)                
        }
        ]))


-----
```

> The error: 
>   [image]

---

> Touching Variable

```
  if countTouch > 10 {

      for touch: AnyObject in touches {
           let skView = self.view! as SKView
          skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
           var scene: Congrats!
          scene =  Congrats(size: skView.bounds.size)
           scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
           skView.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.doorsOpenHorizontal(withDuration: 1.0))

        }

     }
```

OR
This error . Can anyone check it.

```
    if firstTouch {
     shownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,    selector: #selector(MyNewGame.decTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TIME_INCREMENT,  target:self, selector: Selector("endGame"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
      firstTouch = false
       }
```

PS: I'm making where player/user touches on a particle and when they reached their limit, I want to transition to the Congrats scene. Can anyone check if I did this right? I believe this is the crash.

This is also the error code when it crashes:

> 0_specialized _fatalerrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never

Comment: Avoid to forcefuly unwrap the optionals. Otherwise you might crash if underlying value is nil. Also, when initializing color using initializer above you should provide RGBA components in the range between 0 and 1, not between 0 and 255.

Comment: Can you show me some code, so I can understand?

Comment: I could do that. Give me a sec to turn on my computer :)

Comment: @SuzyHakobyan how is it that you have dark line numbers? That's very cool.

Comment: You change the theme.

Answer (score 2):

This would be your GameOver class:

```
class GameOver:SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        backgroundColor = .purple
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        if action(forKey: "transitioning") == nil{

            run(SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0),
                SKAction.run() {[unowned self] in //now deinit will be called
                    let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 1.0)

                    //let scene = GameOver(size: (self.view?.frame.size) ?? CGSize(width: 335, height: 667))
                    let scene = Congrats(size: self.size)
                    self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
                }
                ]), withKey:"transitioning")


        }else{
            print("Transitioning in progress") //Just for a debug, you can remove this else statement
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print("GameOver scene deinitialized")
    }
}
```

and a Congrats class:

```
class Congrats: SKScene {

    let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(248.0 / 255.0), green: CGFloat(248.0 / 255.0), blue: CGFloat(248.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)

        label.text = "Good Job! "
        label.fontSize = 22
        label.fontColor = SKColor.blue
        label.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)

        addChild(label)

    }

    deinit {
        print("Congrats scene deinitialized")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        if action(forKey: "transitioning") == nil{

            run(SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0),
                SKAction.run() {[unowned self] in //now deinit will be called.
                    let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 1.0)

                    //let scene = GameOver(size: (self.view?.frame.size) ?? CGSize(width: 335, height: 667))
                    let scene = GameOver(size: self.size)
                    self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
                }
                ]), withKey:"transitioning")


        }else{
            print("Transitioning in progress") //Just for a debug, you can remove this else statement
        }
    }

}
```

About [UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor) initializer...As I said, it accepts values from 0 to 1 rather than 0 to 255. Also you probably want to change values right now, because you are currently getting something similar to white color.

About forced unwrapping...I just skipped using that all, and used self.size for scene size. Also I commented a line where I use nil coalescing operator (??) which provides a default value to be used if optional's underlying value is nil. Or if you don't want to use that, you can use optional binding syntax (if let ...).

Comment: @Confused Thanks Confused...Missed that one.

Comment: No worries. I frigging hate the messy nonsense of UI/SK color. So longwinded and messy to create a colour.

Comment: @Confused Something like this might work : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27736004/3402095 A bit convenient way to create colors. It lets you doing something like `let myColor = UIColor(r: 255 , g: 255, b: 255, a: 255)`

Comment: Cheers. Better than waiting for Apple to realise Bret Victor might be onto something.

Comment: @SuzyHakobyan I tried this code and if you try it you will see that it work in an empty project. Anyway, you can set an exception break point and see which line causes the error.

Comment: thank you anyways, I wil keep you update if anything happens.

Comment: @SuzyHakobyan No problem. Checkout this link to learn more about exception breakpoint : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802942/3402095

Comment: Can you check my updated question. The Touching Variable.

Answer (score 0):

Move the entire code to override func didMove(to view: SKView). It'll work. Just tested